# Getting text from a paragraph in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This might be a very simple thing in jquery but I am not able to figure it out. My html document has the following structure

```
 <div class="body"> 
 <a href="/question?id=70"><p>This is the text I want to extract</p></a> 
 </div>
```

I tried this

```
$("body").find("a p").text()
```

but this does not seem to be working for me. I am able to get the paragraph object but not the text. I tested it with console.log with no use.

Comment: If `text()` is not working for you, you might not be selecting what you think you should be.

Comment: $("body") != $(".body") - the first get tag body, the second gets body class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have should be working ([you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aSwN5/)), make sure you're running it when the DOM is ready though, like this:

```
$(function() {
  alert($("body").find("a p").text()); //or just $("a p").text()
});
```

If it runs earlier, the elements may not be ready, and your selector won't find any matches.

If you want to select the **class** `body` make sure to use `".body"` instead of `"body"` (which would select the `<body>` element).  Here's a version using the [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(function() {
  alert($(".body a p").text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for jsfiddle.. this is what I was searchin for to fiddle with JS.

Comment: I was missing the . before the class name, I forgot about it :) Topera also found the bug

Answer (score 0):

the .html() function retrieves a nodes inner html.

```
$('.body a p').html();
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would cause a problem, but you have invalid markup. From "[The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)" by the W3C

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

`a` elements are supposed to be contained by block elements like `p`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

here is your paragraph element in html or php file which is id assign tt

```html
<p id="tt">ALert Message </p>
```

in in jquery file to get the text of your paragraph with tt id can be

```html
var tt = $("#tt").text();
alert(tt);
```

working fine for jquery-3.1.1.js